# Trouble assigning background color on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to change the design of my hamburger navigation as the user scrolls. I feel I have come semi close https://jsfiddle.net/g95kk7yh/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 10) {
                $(".navigation").css('background', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)');
                $(".navigation span").css('background', '#bdccd4');
            } else {
                $(".navigation").css('background', 'transparent');
                $(".navigation span").css('background', '#fff');
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

The main problem I'm having is assigning the correct width and height of the red box without repositioning the navigation menu as a whole.

Also is it possible to only have these changes at 600px and under (as you can see this is when the hamburger menu shows).

Comment: just a slight note: setting `background-color` or `background` with a color only is basically the same thing...

Comment: Check this one **https://jsfiddle.net/moj7z2b4/2/** Let me know if its ok.

Comment: @7urkm3n why don't you add it as an answer? looks like the correct one to me...

Comment: Perfect thanks 7urkm3n ...Could you put it as an answer in case anyone refers back to this and would like a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used @potatopeelings post and have changed few lines and added.

```
.myClass {
  margin-right: -25px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/moj7z2b4/2/

Comment: well, to be precise, @potatopeelings did not actually answer the OP's question (at least not at the moment I'm writing this); you just used his approach of doing the same thing as the OP did, but actually provided a solution, so +1 from me...

Comment: @webeno Thank You)

Answer (score 3):

This covers only the 2nd part of the question (thanks @webeno and @MarcusPorter for catching that). Refer to [7urkm3n's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36383725/360067) for an answer that covers both parts of the question.

---

Instead of changing the CSS properties in your script, just add / remove a class that has the properties you need.

```
...
if(scroll_pos > 10) {
    $(".navigation").addClass('myClass')
} else {
    $(".navigation").removeClass('myClass')
}
...
```

Then wrap your class CSS rules with

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .myClass {
        ...
    }

    .myClass span {
        ...
    }
}
```

so that these rules only apply on screen size < 600px

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/moj7z2b4/

Comment: that doesn't really make it look like on the image, the fiddle behaves exactly like the OP's except it's approaches the solution in a different way...

Comment: ...also you haven't talked in your above answer about the part of "only have these changes at 600px and under", though you did change that in the fiddle

Comment: Thanks potatopeelings, this approach may fix my 600px width issue but from what I've played around with so far it doesn't seem to fix my main issue of successfully adding the red box without messing up the positioning of the rest of the navigation. I will play around a bit more and let you know how I go.

Comment: @webeno - you're right, I totally missed the first part of the question and was responding only to the 2nd part. oops! but 7urkm3n has filled in the rest. yaay!

Comment: @MarcusPorter - as webeno pointed out, I totally missed the first part of your question (was probably distracted by the image :-)) and was responding only to the 2nd part of your question. Glad you got it sorted out with 7urkm3n's help. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings Right sorry for the obtrusive image, thanks for the help mr peelings :)

Comment: @MarcusPorter - oh no, I was just kidding. it just missed it while reading the question. Your question was clear and very well framed. Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings I'd like to remove my downvote, can you "help me" with updating your answer, say, referring to the correct one...? ;) cheers

Comment: @webeno - I have done myself the favour :-). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem as well, it was when I was creating the 'preloader' thing for my website. Anyway, the way I resolved my problem was to change `background-color` with `backgroundColor`. Make sure `backgroundColor` isn't in quotation marks, just type it in as you would do with a variable or a function, etc.

From [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc-1):

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both `.css({ "background-color": "#ffe", "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" })` and `.css({backgroundColor: "#ffe", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" })`. Notice that with the DOM notation, quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name.

This code *should* work but I haven't tested it. I changed your `.css('property', 'value')` to `.css({'property': 'value'`});

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scroll_pos = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_pos > 10) {
      $(".navigation").css({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
      });
      $(".navigation span").css({
        'background': '#bdccd4'
      });
    } else {
      $(".navigation").css({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      });
      $(".navigation span").css({
        'background': '#fff'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: functionally there should be absolutely no difference between the two... as also stated in your quote, it just talks about the fact that both can be used, ie. "jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both"...

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I don't feel it's relevant :)

Comment: I suggest you delete this answer on grounds of it being irrelevant to the original question, you'd save yourself a couple of points as my downvote would be removed... ;)